Detecting malicious behaviour
Reverse Engineering is clearly a 'gray'-area with law. Thus this is why I wonder, what to do when you detect a string of questions or a single questions that is clearly leading to mal-behaviour. 

And something legal in a country might be illegal in another. Also, it's not always easy to determine if a behavior is malicious: it depends on the intent.

This is true, also we are not lawyers. As SE is not a Forum you can't PM a Moderator about your concerns.
I for one, would like a formal statement about this.

What exactly do you mean by "mal-behavior"? Any specific examples? BTW, to "PM" mods, use the "flag" link.

@IgorSkochinsky Actually, chat would be preferable for "PM"s as flags may not always be appropriate to express an opinion.

I posted an answer on A51 regarding a similar issue with the TOR proposal. That answer largely covers the same ground.

I posted an answer on A51 regarding a similar issue with the TOR proposal. That answer largely covers the same ground. 
Basically, unless a question itself is mentioning or linking to something that can be construed to be illegal or immoral, then moderators may act on it. However, in most cases, questions may not directly imply an illegal activity and it would be more a matter of judging intent. 
Intent is, quite rightly, not mentioned at all in the TOS, and hence, moderators or users cannot reasonably act (delete) on the basis of perceived intent alone (You are however free to comment and downvote as needed). In such cases, the post is treated as normal and we defer to the Community Team's decision, if at all the situation so demands.

Just to be explicitly clear, everybody is welcome to comment, clarify and vote on such questions howsoever they feel, to bring out the intended use case/scenario. Moderators however, cannot unilaterally act (delete, close) against such posts for reasons of possible intent. 
